# Corner detection in an array of points

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, point-clouds, corner-detection

I get a pointcloud from my lidar which is basically an numpy array of points in 2D cartesian coordinates. Is there any efficient way to detect corners formed by such 2D points?

What I tried until now was to detect clusters, then apply RANSAC on each cluster to detect two lines and then estimate the intersection point of those two lines. This method works well when I know how many clusters I have (in this case I put 3 boxes in front of my robot) and when the surrounding of the robot is free and no other objects are detected.

What I would like to do is run a general corner detection, then take the points surrounding each corner and check if lines are orthogonal. If it is the case then I can consider this corner as feature. This would make my algorithm more flexible when it comes to the surrounding environment.

Here is a visualization of the data I get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many many ways to do this. First thing I'd try in your case would be to chain with a reasonable distance threshold for discontinuities, using the natural lidar scan ordering of the points. Then it become a problem of either estimating local curature or, as you have done, grow and merge linear segments.

Comment: Actually I forgot about the natural ordering of the lidar scan points. What I tried now is a smoothing to reduce the noise, detection of all minima that have are smaller than at least n neighbor points, then merge minima that are too close to each other, finally extract clusters of points around each minimum and perform line detection and validate if the detected lines are orthogonal.

Comment: Hum, makes sense, kinda. The smoothing step seem suspicious to me - why throw away information before you know for sure that it is "noise"? Do you have a model for the noise process? Also, if by "line detection" you mean fitting a straight line to neighboring points, keep in mind that you will need a robustifier (e.g. LMedS, going the full-bore RANSAC/MLESAC is probably rendundant). The robustifier is where it is proper to introduce a noise model, since you are making your model explicit (i.e. the straight line) at that step. Last, please upvote/accept if you find the answer useful.